# Anypoint Studio - Manage API is disabled

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm doing the training course called: Anypoint Platform Development: Fundamentals (Mule 4) from https://training.mulesoft.com/.

In WT4-5, I was instructed as "Right-click the training4-american-ws project in Anypoint Studio and select Manage Dependencies > Manage APIs".  However it is disabled.  Any ideas as to why or how to enable it?

I have my credential's entered in the Authentication section.

Update:

Clicking on Project Properties/Mule Project/APIs

I see a message  *Your current Private Cloud Edition does not allow API dependencies.*

Comment: By disabled you mean `grayed` ? If so, then it shouldn't be. What's your studio version ? Try to create a sample new mule project and see if you are still finding it grayed.

Comment: Yes, it is grayed out.  Version 7.6.0.  Same result for a new project as well.

Comment: why don't try 7.5.1 or 7.4.2 and do the same steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the product resolved the error.